# find and limit array values in an array from a document

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I can explain my issue using facebook as example,

take one news feed(one post), which has

**post-content,images,videos**

**likes,comments,share**

I'm saving the post_content,images,video(urls only) and like count in one collection called **post**

and all the likes in another collection called **post_likes**

now in the timeline I'm getting top 10 posts from the db

```
Posts.find({},{sort: {createdAt: -1}}.limit(10)
```

now, whenever user clicks on like, I'm calling a method which inserts the userid into the collection

```
post_likes.update({post_id:id},{$push:{userids: this.userId}})
```

**post_likes object**

```
{_id:"xxxx",post_id:"Id of the post",userids:["xxx","yyy",....]
```

I'm displaying in my template using

```
{{#each posts}}
.............
.........
........
.......
 {{#if likes}}
 //show dislike button
 {{else}}
 //show like button
 {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

**Here my issue is**

I want to know that current user is liked particular post or not.

I can't load all the liked_users to client side and check.

So I want to publish only one value from array to client

How to do this?

or Is there any alternatives to do this, any idea is welcome and appreaciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several alternatives:

1. Publish **post_likes** for each user:

   ```
   Meteor.publish('user_post_likes', function() {
       return post_likes.find({userids: this.userId});
   });
   ```
2. Attach the post id to the user doc as well as vice versa:

   ```
   post_likes.update({post_id:id},{$push:{userids: this.userId}}); // AND
   Meteor.users.update({_id: this.userId}, {$push: {'profile.post_likes': id}});
   ```

   Then you will have the likes already present in the user doc to which Meteor automatically subscribes.  You can use something like *matb33:collection-hooks* to keep the two collections in sync if required.
3. Write a method to retrieve liked posts on demand:

   ```
   Meteor.methods({
       get_liked_posts: function() {
           return post_likes.find({userids: this.userId});
       }
   });
   ```

The third is less "meteoric", but may be preferable if having lots of users subscribe to their own posts_likes subscriptions independently is hard work for the server.  However, in that event, option 2 might be preferable instead.